# How to enforce terraform destroy?

Tags: terraform

```
terraform destroy -var-file='filename' 

**Do you really want to destroy?**

  Terraform will delete all your managed infrastructure.
  There is no undo. Only 'yes' will be accepted to confirm.
```

However, I want to change the command such that it will destroy without asking the question **Do you really want to destroy?** So what argument should I provide it ?

Answer (score 23):

[`terraform destroy -auto-approve`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#auto-approve)

From the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/destroy.html):

> This [destroy] command accepts all the arguments and flags that the apply command accepts, with the exception of a plan file argument.
>
> If `-auto-approve` is set, then the destroy confirmation will not be shown.

Comment: It is still showing that for me??? 
```terraform destroy -auto-approve
var.web_ami_id
  Enter a value: yes```

Comment: Any input variables are still required. It just won't prompt for the "are you sure"